# Merging two two database context to one?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, sql-server-2008, entity-framework, c#-4.0, sql-server-express

In my project I currently have two databases, one that is named ASPNETDB.MDF and another named School.sdf.  ASPNETDB.MDF was created by the .net Default Membership Provider, I made the second one using Entity Framework.  When I go to make this project live, all this information needs to be contained within the same project.  How would I make the app function correctly as if there was only one database instead of the two- how would I merge all of that data, or -at the very least- build a blank database that was ready to be seeded with all necessary information, my School context and the Default Membership Provider information.

Can anybody give me a help on this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can follow this link from MS: http://www.asp.net/web-forms/tutorials/security/membership/creating-the-membership-schema-in-sql-server-cs

It consists of executing the tool aspnet_regsql.exe, located on %WINDIR%\Microsoft.Net\Framework\vFRAMEWORK_VERSION_NUMBER\

> The aspnet_regsql.exe tool is used to add or remove ASP.NET application services to a specified SQL Server database. The ASP.NET application services encompass the schemas for the SqlMembershipProvider and SqlRoleProvider, along with the schemas for the SQL-based providers for other ASP.NET 2.0 frameworks.

This talks about 2.0, but works the same for newer versions.

Answer (score 1):

what you are looking for is here :
[Video Tutorial On Youtube](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=wek-blnTo2w)

focus on the part where they use : Aspnet_regsql.exe ! 
the idea is not to merge the two database, it's to configure your Asp.Net Membership Provider so it can use the Main Database.
Good luck